# DDD: Entity as a factory for value objects?

Tags: domain-driven-design

Would it make sense in DDD to have an Entity that creates value objects?

I have a `Question` with several `Answers`. Question is an entity, while answer is value object. Question holds answers. User creates questions and answers.

[A] Some say to goes with: `question.createAnswer()`. This way, only questions can crete an answer. This way we prevent to have an answer without a question. Yet - it's not the question which creates an answer, but user.

I personally don't feel this - for me it make sense to create an `Answer` and assign it to the question. And this is not a business logic, right?

[B} I am more for e.g. which is natural flow:

```
Question q = new Question();
Answer a = new Answer(q);   // answer can't exist without a question
```

[C] Some other people also goes with:

```
Question q = new Question();
Answer a = new Answer();
q.addAnswer(a);
```

which is 'loose' version of B, since `Answer` may exist without a `Question`; from my point that seems not ok.

Any wisdom on this?

Comment: Better to post these kinds of questions at https://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: you are right somehow was not aware of it

Comment: Just because an object is not an aggregate does not mean that it is necessarily a value object.  Value objects can certainly exist outside of an entity.  For example: `double weight = 10;` followed by `question.setWeight(weight);` is perfectly valid.

Comment: @StijnGeukens Why ? This is bordering on "algorithm and data structure concepts" (programmers) but really more "implementation issues" (SO) IMO

Comment: I do this sort of thing quite frequently.  Can't claim it's a good idea though.  In my case, it avoids the need for knowing the exact class of a answer.  I also use a repository to create the original question so once again, my application does not need to know exact classes of the model objects.  Just the model interfaces.  Helps with having multiple persistence layers.

Answer (score 2):

If you are following Domain Driven Design principles, "Question" will be an Entity and "Answer", a value object and an attribute of Question. Question will have a method setAnswer (assuming there is only one Answer per Question) and it is what you use to specify an Answer to a question.

In pseudocode, this is how the classes are defined:

```
public class Question {
     String question;
     Answer answer;

     public Question(String question) {
         this.question = question;
     }

     public setAnswer(String answer) {
         this.answer = new Answer(answer);
     }

}

public class Answer {
     String answer;

     public Answer(String answer) {
         this.answer = answer;
     }
}
```

and this is how you'll use them:

```
Question q = new Question("What is the capital of Australia?");
q.setAnswer("Canberra");

// use a repository for the Question Entity to persist the question instance
QuestionRepository.add(q);
```

If your requirement calls for tracking which user added an answer then you will need to add a value object called UserId which is an attribute of another entity called User. (Assuming userid is unique for every user)

```
public class UserId {
    String userid;
    public UserId(String userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }
}

public class User {
    UserId userid;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    :
    :
}
```

The following will be how the Answer value object will look like:

```
public class Answer {
     String answer;
     UserId authorUserId;

     public Answer(String answer, UserId userid) {
         this.answer = answer;
         this.authorUserId = userid;
     }
}
```

SetAnswer method in Question needs to be modified to:

```
     public setAnswer(String answer, UserId authorUserId) {
         this.answer = new Answer(answer, authorUserId);
     }
```

Finally, to use it (assuming userid is a variable of type UserId populated with the currently logged in user's userid):

```
Question q = new Question("What is the capital of Australia?");
q.setAnswer("Canberra", userid);
```

Comment: Thanx. Questions: 1) what if `Answer` requires many properties, not only a string? Then we will duplicate the constructor of `Answer` in `setAnswer()` (or `addAnswer()`). Shouldn't we avoid that by simply creating the answer instance by ourselves? 2) Both `Question` and `Answer` may be created without the relationship between. Shouldn't we try to fix that and give hint to developers not to mess up? 3) If `Question` is a factory for `Answer`, how we are prepared for different types of `Answers` in the future (e.g. `CorrectAnswer`, `WrongAnswer`...).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to reason about `Question` more as an Aggregate than the OO representation of an incarnated being/object that does things. A question sure doesn't create its own answer in the real world, but the `Question` *Aggregate* can perfectly expose an `Answer(...)` (as in the verb) method reflecting the fact that client code orders that Aggregate to incorporate the answer just entered by the user.

Options [A] and [B] seem equally good to me, with a preference for [A] if there are invariants in an `Answer` that need data from the `Question` to be enforced, and because [B] probably means a bi-directional relationship between the two. [C] is also possible if you consider that the "can't exist without" rule is addressed by the aggregate design (Answer is necessarily loaded along with a Question, deleted along with it) rather than developer-level precautions.

Overall I think these are details, there are more important things such as making sure the Aggregate is designed with the transactions that will happen in production in mind. A single "Question #35" aggregate root including Answers from all users will probably pose concurrency problems in a highly collaborative context for instance.